# MVC and NOSQL: Saving View Models directly to MongoDB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, separation-of-concerns

I understand that the "proper" structure for separation-of-concerns in MVC is to have view-models for your structuring your views and separate data-models for persisting in your chosen repository.  I started experimenting with MongoDB and I'm starting to think that this may not apply when using a schema-less, NO-SQL style database.  I wanted to present this scenario to the stackoverflow community and see what everyone's thoughts are.  I'm new to MVC, so this made sense to me, but maybe I am overlooking something...

Here is my example for this discussion: When a user wants to edit their profile, they would go to the UserEdit view, which uses the UserEdit model below.

```
public class UserEditModel
{
    public string Username
    {
        get { return Info.Username; }
        set { Info.Username = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    [MembershipPassword]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Email]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public UserInfo Info { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfo : IRepoData
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid _id { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Theme { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool IsADUser { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the UserEditModel class contains an instance of UserInfo that inherits from IRepoData?  UserInfo is what gets saved to the database.  I have a generic repository class that accepts any object that inherits form IRepoData and saves it; so I just call `Repository.Save(myUserInfo)` and its's done.  IRepoData defines the _id (MongoDB naming convention) and a Timestamp, so the repository can upsert based on _id and check for conflicts based on the Timestamp, and whatever other properties the object has just get saved to MongoDB.  The view, for the most part, just needs to use `@Html.EditorFor` and we are good to go! Basically, anything that just the view needs goes into the base-model, anything that only the repository needs just gets the `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` annotation, and everything else is common between the two. *(BTW - the username, password, roles, and email get saved to .NET providers, so that is why they are not in the UserInfo object.)*

The **big advantages** of this scenario are two-fold...

1. I can use **less code**, which is therefore more easily understood, faster to develop, and more maintainable (in my opinion).
2. I can **re-factor** in seconds... If I need to add a second email address, I just add it to the UserInfo object - it gets added to the view and saved to the repository just by adding one property to the object.  Because I am using MongoDB, I don't need to alter my db schema or mess with any existing data.

Given this setup, is there a need to make separate models for storing data?  What do you all think the disadvantages of this approach are?  I realize that the obvious answers are standards and separation-of-concerns, but are there any real world examples can you think of that would demonstrate some of the headaches this would cause?

Its also worth noting that I'm working on a team of two developers total, so it's easy to look at the benefits and overlook bending some standards.  Do you think working on a smaller team makes a difference in that regard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advantages of view models in MVC exist regardless of database system used (hell even if you don't use one).  In simple CRUD situations, your business model entities will very closely mimick what you show in the views, but in anything more than basic CRUD this will not be the case.

One of the big things are business logic / data integrity concerns with using the same class for data modeling/persistence as what you use in views.  Take the situation where you have a `DateTime DateAdded` property in your user class, to denote when a user was added.  If you provide an form that hooks straight into your `UserInfo` class you end up with an action handler that looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserInfo model) { }
```

Most likely you don't want the user to be able to change when they were added to the system, so your first thought is to not provide a field in the form.

However, you can't rely on that for two reasons.  First is that the value for `DateAdded` will be the same as what you would get if you did a `new DateTime()` or it will be `null` ( either way will be incorrect for this user).

The second issue with this is that users can spoof this in the form request and add `&DateAdded=<whatever date>` to the POST data, and now your application will change the DateAdded field in the DB to whatever the user entered.

This is by design, as MVC's model binding mechanism looks at the data sent via POST and tries to automatically connect them with any available properties in the model.  It has no way to know that a property that was sent over wasn't in the originating form, and thus it will still bind it to that property.

ViewModels do not have this issue because your view model should know how to convert itself to/from a data entity, and it does not have a `DateAdded` field to spoof, it only has the bare minimum fields it needs to display (or receive) it's data.

In your exact scenario, I can reproduce this with ease with POST string manipulation, since your view model has access to your data entity directly.

Another issue with using data classes straight in the views is when you are trying to present your view in a way that doesn't really fit how your data is modeled.  As an example, let's say you have the following fields for users:

```
public DateTime? BannedDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? ActivationDate { get; set; } // Date the account was activated via email link
```

Now let's say as an Admin you are interested on the status of all users, and you want to display a status message next to each user as well as give different actions the admin can do based on that user's status.  If you use your data model, your view's code will look like:

```
// In status column of the web page's data grid

@if (user.BannedDate != null)
{
    <span class="banned">Banned</span>
}
else if (user.ActivationDate != null)
{
    <span class="Activated">Activated</span>
}

//.... Do some html to finish other columns in the table
// In the Actions column of the web page's data grid
@if (user.BannedDate != null)
{
    // .. Add buttons for banned users
}
else if (user.ActivationDate != null)
{
    // .. Add buttons for activated  users
}
```

This is bad because you have a lot of business logic in your views now (user status of banned always takes precedence over activated users, banned users are defined by users with a banned date, etc...).  It is also much more complicated.

Instead, a better (imho at least) solution is to wrap your users in a ViewModel that has an enumeration for their status, and when you convert your model to your view model (the view model's constructor is a good place to do this) you can insert your business logic once to look at all the dates and figure out what status the user should be.

Then your code above is simplified as:

```
// In status column of the web page's data grid

@if (user.Status == UserStatuses.Banned)
{
    <span class="banned">Banned</span>
}
else if (user.Status == UserStatuses.Activated)
{
    <span class="Activated">Activated</span>
}

//.... Do some html to finish other columns in the table
// In the Actions column of the web page's data grid
@if (user.Status == UserStatuses.Banned)
{
    // .. Add buttons for banned users
}
else if (user.Status == UserStatuses.Activated)
{
    // .. Add buttons for activated  users
}
```

Which may not look like less code in this simple scenario, but it makes things a lot more maintainable when the logic for determining a status for a user becomes more complicated.  You can now change the logic of how a user's status is determined without having to change your data model (you shouldn't have to change your data model because of how you are viewing data) and it keeps the status determination in one spot.

Comment: I basically agree. In the fifth paragraph, maybe you should point out that model binding is the cause of the problem (i.e. every field with the right name will be bound), and model binding can also be configured to ignore certain fields - even though I'd deem that dangerous. Because mapping code is boring and error-prone, AutoMapper might be a good idea to map to and from ViewModels.

Comment: Ah good point, I'll add that.  And I do agree that automapper is probably a better solution to convert to/from a view model rather than doing it manually.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to make that well-written answer for me!

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

There are at least 3 layers of models in an application, sometimes they can be combined safely, sometimes not.  In the context of the question, it's ok to combine the persistence and domain models but not the view model.

## full post

The scenario you describe fits equally well using any entity model directly.  It could be using a Linq2Sql model as your ViewModel, an entity framework model, a hibernate model, etc.  The main point is that you want to use the persisted model directly as your view model.  Separation of concerns, as you mention, does not explicitly force you to avoid doing this.  In fact separation of concerns is not even the most important factor in building your model layers.

In a typical web application there are at least 3 distinct layers of models, although it is possible and sometimes correct to combine these layers into a single object.  The model layers are, from highest level to lowest, your view model, your domain model and your persistence model.  Your view model should describe exactly what is in your view, no more and no less.  Your domain model should describe your complete model of the system exactly.  Your persistence model should describe your storage method for your domain models exactly.

ORMs come in many shapes and sizes, with different conceptual purposes, and MongoDB *as you describe it* is simply one of them.  The illusion most of them promise is that your persistence model should be the same as your domain model and the ORM is just a mapping tool from your data store to your domain object.  This is certainly true for simple scenarios, where all of your data comes from one place, but eventually has it's limitations, and your storage degrades into something more pragmatic for your situation.  When that happens, the models tend to become distinct.

The one rule of thumb to follow when deciding whether or not you can separate your domain model from your persistence model is whether or not you could easily swap out your data store without changing your domain model.  If the answer is yes, they can be combined, otherwise they should be separate models.  A repository interface naturally fits here to deliver your domain models from whatever data store is available.  Some of the newer light weight ORMs, such as [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and [massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive), make it very easy to use your domain model as your persistence model because they do not require a particular data model in order to perform persistence, you are simply writing the queries directly, and letting the ORM just handle the mapping.

On the read side, view models are again a distinct model layer because they represent a subset of your domain model combined however you need in order to display information to the page.  If you want to display a user's info, with links to all his friends and when you hover over their name you get some info about that user, your persistence model to handle that directly, even with MongoDB, would likely be pretty insane.  Of course not every application is showing such a collection of interconnected data on every view, and sometimes the domain model is exactly what you want to display.  In that case there is no reason to put in the extra weight of mapping from an object that has exactly what you want to display to a specific view model that has the same properties.  In simple apps if all I want to do is augment a domain model, my view model will directly inherit from the domain model and add the extra properties I want to display.  That being said, before your MVC app becomes large, I highly recommend using a view model for your layouts, and having all of page based view models inherit from that layout model.

On the write side, a view model should only allow the properties you wish to be editable for the type of user accessing the view.  Do not send an admin view model to the view for a non admin user.  You *could* get away with this if you write the mapping layer for this model yourself to take into account the privileges of the accessing user, but that is probably more overhead than just creating a second admin model that inherits from the regular view model and augments it with the admin properties.

Lastly about your points:

1. Less code is only an advantage when it actually is more understandable.  Readability and understand-ability of it are results of the skills of the person writing it.  There are famous examples of short code that has taken even solid developers a long time to dissect and understand.  Most of those examples come from cleverly written code which is not more understandable.  More important is that your code meets your specification 100%.  If your code is short, easily understood and readable but does not meet the specification, it is worthless.  If it is all of those things and does meet the specification, but is easily exploitable, the specification **and** the code are worthless.
2. Refactoring in seconds safely is the result of well written code, not it's terseness.  Following the DRY principle will make your code easily refactorable as long as your specification correctly meets your goals.  In the case of model layers, your domain model is the key to writing good, maintainable and easy to refactor code.  Your domain model will change at the pace at which your business requirements change.  Changes in your business requirements are big changes, and care has to be taken to make sure that a new spec is fully thought out, designed, implemented, tested, etc.  For example you say today you want to add a second email address.  You still will have to change the view (unless you're using some kind of scaffolding).  Also, what if tomorrow you get a requirements change to add support for up to 100 email addresses?  The change you originally proposed was rather simple for any system, bigger changes require more work.